# Using exact same data in two separate react child components. One component allows data to be manipulated, the other component does not

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object, fetch

In a react site, I pull in data (array of objects, two key-value pairs per object) in a parent component and pass the data to the children in props. I have two pureComponent children with the exact same data being passed in identical props. However, as soon as I do any kind of data manipulation, even just accessing the first array element (data[0]), one component plays nice and the other says that the data is being returned as [{object Object}, {object Object}, ...] so it throws errors if I try to do anything with it.

### Code

pulling in data in parent component:

```
const mainstem = 'dataUrl'
          fetch(mainstem)
          .then(res=>res.json())
          // pop off header row
          .then(res=>res.slice(1,res.length))
          // remap data structure
          .then(res=>res.map(entry=>{
            return {
              discharge: parseInt(entry[1]) ? parseInt(entry[1]) : 0,
              date: new Date(entry[0])
            }
          }))
          .then(mainstem=>this.setState({
            mainstem
          }))
```

This results in an array of objects, each object has two key-value pairs, the first is a number with up to two decimal points and the second is a date (string that includes numbers).

example:

```
console.log(this.state.mainstem);

(672) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
```

expanding one of the objects (index 0) in the array:

```
0:
date: "Sat Aug 31 2019"
discharge: 0
__proto__: Object
```

Passing the data as props to child components in render:

```
<SmallChart data={this.state.mainstem} width={this.state.width}/>
<CurrentDay data={this.state.mainstem}/>
```

Using the data in the child components:
"Current Day" Component:

```
export default class CurrentDay extends PureComponent {

  render() {

    const data = this.props.data ? this.props.data.map(entry=>(
      {
        discharge: entry.discharge,
        date: entry.date.toDateString()
      }
    )) : null;
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data[0].date)

    // Step 1 - store current date in a variable
      // const currentDate = data[0].date;
      // console.log(data[0].date);
      // console.log(data);
      // console.log(`current date: `+currentDate);
    // Step 2 - make array of discharges that happen on current date

    // Step 3 - var currentTotal = sum of all entries in array

    return(
      <div>
        <p>Today's Total Flow: {currentTotal} million gallons</p> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The console.log(data) initially shows two instances of null in the console, but then it correctly shows the exact same data as when I did the console.log(this.state.mainstem) in the parent:

```
(672) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
```

, BUT console.log(data[0].date) just shows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
```

and I get the same error whenever I try to access any part of the data, which is clearly being pulled in correctly.

Oddly enough, the other child component (Small Chart) allows for access to the exact same data:

```
export default class SmallChart extends PureComponent {

  render() {
    const data = this.props.data ? this.props.data.map(entry=>(
      {
        discharge: entry.discharge,
        date: entry.date.toDateString()
      }
    )) : null;
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data[0].date);

    .
    .
    .
```

Both of these console.logs properly show the data and the current date:
console:

```
(672) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
```

`Sat Aug 31 2019`

Any idea on why handling the data in two nearly identical child components would result in one child being able to access and manipulate the data in any way, but the other child has the data, but it says that the data is null whenever I try to access a specific index or manipulate it in any way?

---

UPDATE: Possibly fixed? As soon as I made sure the parent was only rendering the children if data was available to them, the console logs started working. Seems like it's fixed, but I won't know for sure until I try to really work with the data in the children. Once I do this, I will write another update.

Here's how I am now rendering the child components:

```
{this.state.mainstem ? 
              <>
                <SmallChart data={this.state.mainstem} width={this.state.width}/> 
                <CurrentDay data={this.state.mainstem}/>
              </>
            : null}
```

Comment: It will be better to provide some codes. Actually, it is a little hard to understand what is the problem.

Comment: Can't help you without the code

Comment: The common reason might be the fact that you are directly rendering the array rather than mapping over it.

Comment: I added lots of code and console logs. Hopefully this helps and I would appreciate if anyone who downvoted can undo that now so that I can get some visibility on this question.

Would also be nice to get taken off hold, but I have no idea how that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was that I was trying to pass data to the current day component without making sure that the data was available for it. I changed the code so that when these components are rendered, they are both only rendered if the relevant data is available for them.

Here's how I am now rendering the child components:

```
{this.state.mainstem ? 
              <>
                <SmallChart data={this.state.mainstem} width={this.state.width}/> 
                <CurrentDay data={this.state.mainstem}/>
              </>
            : null}
```

Another thing to keep in mind as far as the console.logs go is that you can't console.log a string attached to an array, object, etc (anything other than a string). Therefore, when I tried to do something like console.log('my data: ' + data), it would show as "my data: [object Object]". Instead, you should do two separate console logs, the first with the string and the second with the data/array/object/whatever.